# Can I manually call my RegularExpressionAttribute from controller?

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Is this a bad idea? Just seems like it would be nice to be able to reuse regex

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class SafeInputAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Regular expression for safeinput
  /// </summary>
  public SafeInputAttribute()
    : base(@"[^{}<>]+$")
  {
  }
}
```

Something like this?

```
    SafeInputAttribute safeInput = new SafeInputAttribute();
    safeInput.Validate(pin, "Login Pin");
```

It doesn't work, safeinput is null.

Appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure `safeinput` is null? I can't see any reason why it would be. To invoke your validator manually you can do this:

```
SafeInputAttribute validator = new SafeInputAttribute();
bool valid = validator.IsValid(testValue);
```